# Vite/ES6 - How to prevent importing duplicate scripts that may already be loaded

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vite

I'm admittedly late to the ES6 party and have been using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and am a little confused on what would be considered best practice for my specific scenario:

I'm working on a frontend WordPress plugin for a client, however since WP runs inside of the theme which already includes jQuery I don't want to re-import it and bloat the plugin scripts as a result.

I've been experimenting with [this topic](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/3744#discussioncomment-1930660) but I'm just a little confused on how `import` vs `import()` works in terms of bundling.

Is there a way to import jQuery without affecting the bundle size if I *know* it will be externally available after build?

Does `rollupOptions.external` prevent it from being included?